# $\int_{0}^{1}\phi(t)e^{-at}dt =0$ for every $a>0$ implies $\int_{0}^{1}\phi(t)t^ndt =0.$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, proof-verification

Suppose $\phi: [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, and that for every $a>0$ we have $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}\phi(t)e^{-at}dt =0$ then show that for every non-negative integer $n$ we have $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}\phi(t)t^ndt =0.$

**My attempt:** Let $f_n(t)= \phi(t)e^{-\frac{t}{n}}$ so that $f(t) = \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(t)= \phi(t).$ Also, for every $n \in \mathbb{N},$ and $t\in [0,1]$,  it's clear that $|f_n(t)|\leq |\phi(t)|,$ which is an integrable function on $[0,1]$ as it is continuous. Then by the dominated convergence theorem, we have $0=\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}f_n(t)dt= \displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}\phi(t)dt.$

Let $F(x)= \displaystyle \int_{0}^{x}\phi(t)dt$ then since $\phi$ is continuous, by the fundamental theorem of calculus, $F$ is differentiable and $F'(x)= \phi(x)$ for all $x \in [0,1].$ Also from above, $F(1)=0.$

For non-zero $a$, integrating $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}\phi(t)e^{-at}dt$ by parts we get

$\begin{align}0&= \displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}\phi(t)e^{-at}dt\\&=e^{-at} F(t)\bigg|_{0}^{1} +a \displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}F(t)e^{-at}dt\end{align}$

$\Rightarrow \displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}F(t)e^{-at}dt =0$

Since $a>0$ was arbitrary it follows by the same dominated convergence argument used above that $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}F(t)dt =0.$ Using integration by parts once more we get $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}F(t)dt = -\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}t\phi(t)dt$ so $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}t\phi(t)dt=0.$

Now setting $G(x)= \displaystyle \int_{0}^{x}F(t)dt$ and repeating the above argument on $G$ in place of $F$ we get $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}tF(t)dt=0.$ Since $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}tF(t)dt = -2\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}t^2\phi(t)dt$ it follows that $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}t^2\phi(t)dt=0.$

Continuing this process for successive anti-derivatives of $\phi$ it follows that $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}t^n\phi(t)dt=0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}.$

**Question:** Is this proof correct? If no, what is the flaw? If yes, is there a method that does not proceed case-by-case?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof seems fine. So let me introduce two more proofs, where one is elementary but problem-specific and the other is more advanced but robust.

---

**1<sup>st</sup> Proof.** By the [*Taylor's theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder), for $n \geq 0$

$$ \forall a > 0, \ \forall t \geq 0 \ : \quad \left| e^{-at} - \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} (at)^k \right| \leq \frac{(at)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}. $$

Now define $P_n(a) := \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \left( \int_{0}^{1} t^k \phi(t) \, dt \right) a^k$. Then $P_n$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n$. Moreover, by the identity $\int_{0}^{1}\phi(t)e^{-at} \, dt = 0$, we find that for $a > 0$,

$$ \left| P_n(a) \right| = \left| \int_{0}^{1} \phi(t) \left( e^{-at} - \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} (at)^k \right) \, dt \right| \leq \frac{a^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} \int_{0}^{1} t^{n+1} \lvert \phi(t) \rvert \, dt. $$

This is enough to conclude that $P_n \equiv 0$ and hence $\int_{0}^{1} t^k \phi(t) \, dt = 0$ for $k = 0, \cdots, n$. (See Lemma below, for instance.) But since $n$ was arbitrary, this is true for all $k \geq 0$. ////

- **Lemma.** Let $P(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} c_k x^k$ be a polynomial of degree at most $n$. If there exists $C \geq 0$ such that $\lvert P(x) \rvert \leq Cx^{n+1}$ for all $x > 0$, then $c_k = 0$ for each $k = 0, \cdots, n$.

  *Proof of Lemma.* We obtain $a_0 = 0$ from the computation

  $$ 0 \leq \left| a_0 \right| = \lim_{x \to 0^+} \left| P(x) \right| \leq \lim_{x\to0^+} Cx^{n+1} = 0. $$

  Likewise, if we have discovered that $a_0 = \cdots = a_{k-1} = 0$ for $k \in \{1, \cdots, n\}$, then

  $$ 0 \leq \left| a_k \right| = \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\left| P(x) \right|}{x^k} \leq \lim_{x\to0^+} Cx^{n+1-k} = 0 $$

  and hence $a_k = 0$. Therefore the claim follows by induction on $k$. ////

---

**2<sup>nd</sup> Proof.** We prove the following claim, which is enough for initiating induction in OP's case.

> **Theorem.** Let $\varphi : [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function such that $t \mapsto \varphi(t)e^{-at}$ is integrable on $[0,\infty)$ for each $a > 0$. Define
>
> $$L(a) := \int_{0}^{\infty} \varphi(t)e^{-at} \, dt. $$
>
> Then
>
> 1. $L$ is differentiable on $(0, \infty)$ with the derivative $L'(a) = - \int_{0}^{\infty} t \varphi(t)e^{-at} \, dt$.
> 2. If $\varphi$ is integrable, then $L(a) \to L(0)$ as $a \to 0^+$.

*Proof.* Part 2 is a straightforward application of the dominated convergence theorem. Assume that $\varphi$ is integrable. Then $t \mapsto \varphi(t)e^{-a t}$ is dominated by $\lvert \varphi(t) \rvert$. So $L(a_n) \to L(0)$ as $n\to\infty$ along any sequence $(a_n)$ of positive reals such that $a_n \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. Therefore $L(a) \to L(0)$ as $a \to 0^+$.

Next we prove Part 2. Write $G(a) = - \int_{0}^{\infty} t \varphi(t)e^{-at} \, dt$. This is well-defined since $t \mapsto t \varphi(t)e^{-at}$ is integrable on $[0, \infty)$ for each $a > 0$. (To argue this, simply use the bound $t \leq (2/a)e^{at/2}$.) Now fix $a > 0$. Then for any $h$ with $0 < \lvert h \rvert < a/2$,

\begin{align*}
\left| \frac{L(a+h) - L(a)}{h} - G(a) \right|
&\leq \int_{0}^{\infty} \underbrace{ \lvert \varphi(t) \rvert e^{-at} \left| \frac{e^{-ht} - 1}{h} + t \right| }_{(*)} \, dt
\end{align*}

We make some observations on the integrand $\text{(*)}$.

- By the mean-value theorem, $ \left| \frac{e^{-ht} - 1}{h} \right| \leq t e^{at/2} $ and hence $\text{(*)}$ is dominated by the integrable function $ t \lvert \varphi(t) \rvert e^{-at} (e^{at/2}+1) $.
- As $h\to 0$, $\text{(*)}$ converges pointwise to $0$.

Thus along any sequence $(h_n)$ with $0 < \lvert h_n \rvert < a/2$ and $h_n \to 0$, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \text{(*)} \, dt = 0$ by the dominated convergence theorem. This implies that

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{L(a+h_n) - L(a)}{h_n} = G(a). $$

Since this is true for all such $(h_n)$, it follows that $\frac{L(a+h) - L(a)}{h} \to G(a)$ as $h \to 0$. ////

Comment: Thanks for adding the second proof. I have a few of questions about it: 1) am I right in saying that the proof carries through if $L$ is defined to be $L(a)= \displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}t\phi(t)e^{-at}dt$? 2) What was your motivation behind arriving at that expression for $L'(a)?$ 3) By differentiating under the integral sign, we get $L'(a)=-aL(a)$ but solving this differential equation won't help since we know $L$ (as defined in this comment) is identically $0.$ Can this relation tell us anything else given your expression of $L'(a)$ too?

Comment: @AryamanJal, 1) No. $L(a)$ is the Laplace transform of $\phi$, which means that (in your case) $$L(a) = \int_{0}^{1}\color{red}{\boxed{\phi(t)e^{-at}}}\,dt.$$ 2) It is motivated by the [*Leibniz's integral rule*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule), i.e., differentiating under integral sign. 3) I am not sure what you mean. The expression for $L'(a)$ is exactly what we get when differentiating under integral sign, and except for some special cases, it is not written only in terms of $L(a)$.

Comment: Regrading 2) and 3), I made a silly mistake while differentiating so that differential equation I wrote is wrong. Part 1) of the claim is then simply using Leibniz' integral rule but I like your first principles argument. Regarding 1) maybe I need to read more about the Laplace transform, but I don't see how the induction is initiated in this set up. Can you give me a hint in this direction? Or does it follow from an application of dominated convergence to $L'(a)$?

Comment: @AryamanJal As you pointed out, I was simply proving that differentiating under integral sign is available in this setting. (Two limit operators do not necessarily commute in arbitrary setting, so it is important to know when they do.) As for applying this theorem to your problem, notice that $$L^{(n)}(a)=(-1)^n\int_{0}^{1}t^n\phi(t)e^{-at}\,dt$$ is again a Laplace transform, which this is identically zero by the assumption. Since $t^n\phi(t)$ is integrable, $$\int_{0}^{1}t^n\phi(t)\,dt=(-1)^nL^{(n)}(0)=\lim_{a\to0^+}(-1)^nL^{(n)}(a)=0.$$

Comment: I changed notation in the statement and the proof of Theorem to avoid confusion. In the above comment, I am applying the theorem to $\varphi(t) = t^n\phi(t)\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}(t)$ for each $n\geq 0$.